# Impossible to install/run Ubuntu 18.04/18.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, crash, microcode

Sorry for my bad English:
I'm totally new at Ubuntu, and i'm trying to install it in dual boot with W10 in my laptop (hp omen 15, i7 7700hq, 12gbram, gtx1050, hdd 1tb, ssd crucial 275gb m.2, the usb I'm using is a 32gb kingston 3.0).

I've tried 11 times (literally) installing ubuntu, and it always crashes when I hit the `reboot now` button, it freezes for about 3 minutes in the `reboot now` screen, and after that gives an error in a black screen. It never has boot on Ubuntu after that. Got to say that almost all time I've tried with the laptop disconnected from any powersource and with the external peripherals also disconnected, as I've read that sometimes it gets stuck if you have two monitors and similar things.

On early tries it used to give microcode errors (0x52 if I remember well), but now (it's supposed that I've updated the microcodes) it gives other ones. (I'll put photos later). Almost always it finished with two messages `Syncronizing SCSI cache`, this one for the sda and sdb devices.

When I try to install it on the SSD I'm using a partition of 50gb ext4 on `/` and another swap of 5gbs, and when I try that on the HDD I've used two partitions apart from the swap of 5gbs, one called root and other one called home, the first one on `/` and the second on `/home`, each one of 50gbs.

What I've tried:

- Update microcode and BIOS (F50 now, before was at F34).
- Install it via different USB devices, and in ISO and DD modes (those which Rufus gives, and yes, always in GPT, my bios is in uefi mode).
- Install it on the SSD and on the HDD, as sometimes the error after pressing the `reboot button` was `[sdc]No caching mode was found`. SDA is the SSD, SDB the HDD and SDC the USB, but idk, I wanted to try.
- Install 18.04LTS and 18.10, but neither worked.
- Install it directly when it boots on my usb via `install now` and also via `try ubuntu`.
- Install it having the secure boot activated, now it's deactivated.
- I've also tried taking of the usb after pressing reboot, as sometimes it said that no cache page was found at sdc, it repeated the error despite not being inserted on the usb port.

I don't know which is the problem and how to solve it... Thanks in advance.

FINALLY, I managed to install Lubuntu 18.10 (I gave up with Ubuntu) but I don't manage my laptop to detect the external monitor (via HDMI), I´ve googled and anything, since directly it doesn't detect it (now I´m writing on it on W10 so it works properly and I´ve tried rebooting Lubuntu with no success). Does anyone have any idea of what could I do? Thanks in advande.

(I don´t know if I should make this question on another different post, if yes, let me know :) ).

Comment: have you tried to add `nomodeset` to your grub2 boot up OS parms ?   see details : How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?   https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: yes avoid any external monitor until it boots correctly because some pre-boot ways of booting up do not sent anything to external monitors

Comment: /swap is no longer needed. One ext4 partition for root and everything is adequate, for the problems with swap file slowness have been solved. When you install, you do not need to make a separate /swap partition any more.

Answer (score 0):

Boot and repeatedly hit the `Shift` key which will take you to [the grub2 menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

The top line will say something about Ubuntu

The second line will mention Recovery

Use your up/down arrow keys to navigate

Navigate to the top line (which is highlighted by default) and hit `e` to edit

Use arrow keys to get to line which mentions linux ...
it may show a value of `quiet splash`
replace the words `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`

Save and continue to login screen. Once logged on do this edit to make this change permanent by doing this in a terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Now make the same change in the file as you did to boot. Save & exit, then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Let us know if this fixes your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it in dual boot after restart it'll obviously boot in Windows even if you correctly installed Ubuntu.

At the installation Ubuntu 18.04 should recognize there is also another OS on the disk, and it should prompt you if you want to install them in parallel in order for GRUB to handle both OS entries.

If you didn't you'll have to manually launch the partition containing Ubuntu from BIOS.
You can do it in the same way you boot from USB, by moving up the partition containing Ubuntu in the BOOT order.

Comment: When I rebot it doesnt apear grub, not automatically&not manually by presing shift repeatedly. By pressingF9 (select bot dev)yes, and I enter one called Ubuntu, but I think that's an old one (I tried installing it a few months ago with no result, after that formated partitions and PC but it continues to apear, same with phoenixOS that installed few months ago with suces, uninstalled but apears on the boot select menu). In that menu I've tried changing to nomodeset, CTR+X, rn Ubuntu, login, and stuck here: http://bit.ly/2D22Ldw (purplescreen with mouse), dunno if old Ubun or just installed one

Comment: @UrkoUrbieta That's how UEFI works. The Ubuntu entry is certainly updated, not the one from the previous installation. You need to make that the first boot instead of Windows.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia okay, I think I get it. The problem is that despite I try to enter Ubuntu I never achieve, sometimes bcos I get stuck on purple screens, sometimes on black ones...(new error after last installation on the main post, error 2)

Comment: You need `nomodeset` until you install the Nvidia drivers. The link for a question on how to do it was posted in the very first comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu . How to manage boot in the firmware (UEFI) settings and the temporary use of `nomodeset` are the two main things you need to understand if you want to be doing what you're doing. Otherwise leave to the professionals.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia As I said on the "Error 1", I've tried tiping "nomodeset" on the grub, via changing it directly on the grub, and also via recovery->commands (root) with sudo nano /etc/default/grub and then updating the grub, both tries with no success, getting black screen with white line blinkin'.

Comment: @UrkoUrbieta It seems you need to change a few more parameters in the firmware. Namely, if available, the OS selection should be "Linux" or "Android". Secure Boot should also be disabled, at least for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I don't understand well (sorry for my bad English) what you say at the beginning of the answer, If you mean that when I choose the os at boot it's name has to be "Android or Linux", in my case was Ubuntu, but when I chose "advanced options for Ubuntu" there I got Linux 4.xxx... and Linux 4.xxx recovery mode. About the secure boot, it's disabled since the beginning (appart from one or two tries where I enabled it, but now it is disabled). Thanks

Comment: No, I mean the "OS selection" at UEFI settings. Most current low to mid-end light laptops with Intel onboard graphics have that "feature". There may be some additional settings requiring attention. Better to just Goomgle your model name and Ubuntu and/or find a forum (like Ubuntuforums.org) for extensive troubleshooting. I'm afraid it's not possible to give a proper answer in this Q&A format.